# How to put selected element in dropdown by text, index or value with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a select element with this structure:

```
<div class="ddl">
    <select>
        <option selected value="select">Select</option>
        <option value="T">Toyota</option>
        <option value="P">Porsche</option>
        <option value="N">Nissan</option>
        <option value="V">Volkswagen</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And there is no ID of the select element to pass it to the jQuery selector, just the parent class of the div.

How can I put any of these elements as the selected element by text, index or value?

Comment: $('.ddl').find('select').value('T');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to interact with selector.

**Using jQuery 1.6 and upper:**

By text:

```
$('.ddl option:contains("Porsche")').prop('selected', true);
```

By index:

```
$('.ddl option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
```

By value:

```
$('.ddl option[value="T"]').prop('selected', true);
```

---

**With older versions:**

By text:

```
$('.ddl option:contains("Porsche")').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

By index:

```
$('.ddl option:eq(1)').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

By value:

```
$('.ddl option[value="T"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

E.g (Selection with value):

```
$(".ddl select").val("T");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div.ddl >select option:selected').text(); //for getting text
$('div.ddl >select option:selected').val(); //value
$('div.ddl >select option').each(function(){ //looping
alert($(this).val());
});

});
```

Comment: Comment here if you  are having more than 1 div with class ddl

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ddl select").attr("value","T");
```

Answer (score 0):

$('.ddl>select') should work, This is the div of class ddl and the '>' tells jQuery to find a direct child of that class. Watch out for more than one div with class ddl though.